Does "he hit his head on the wall on purpose" sound natural?
If "hit" means to knock a part of your body against something by accident, we can say "He hit his head on/against the low ceiling.". We can also use "bang" instead "She tripped and banged her knee on the desk."
What I mean here is when "hit" means to bring your hand, or an object you are holding, against somebody/something quickly and with force, I don't see any example using this structure "somebody hit a part of his body on something on purpose".
Normally, we say
-"he banged his head on the wall" (bang= hit noisily on purpose)
-"he banged the wall with his head" (bang= hit noisily on purpose)
-"he hit himself on the head with a stick" (hit on purpose)
I am asking this question to say if we can construct a sentence using "hit" (mean: using hands or object to touch something with force deliberately) the same way we use "bang".
-"he banged his head on the wall on purpose" (sound good) and -"he hit his head on the wall on purpose" (sound strange).
Does "he hit his head on the wall on purpose" sound natural?

Do you mean that he bumped his head (so inadvertently) or he intentionally knocked his head into or against the wall. As ever, context and intended meaning matter… a lot.

What does I know the difference between "hit" and "bang" mean here? There are many contexts where there's no difference at all.

@PaulTanenbaump No, I updated my question. I mean if "hit" means "touch something with force on purpose", can we say "he hit his head on the wall on purpose"?

Actually, what we normally say is bang your head against a brick wall (see FumbleFingers' answer). The dictionary uses 'etc' because other verbs such as knock or hit could be used.

@KateBunting, but that is figurative sense, I am talking about literal sense. I don't think you say "he hit his head on the wall on purpose" when you mean he brought an object against something quickly and with force. Instead, "he hit the wall with his head" is better.

I can't imagine in what circumstances a person would do that, except to pretend to do so as a humorous gesture of exasperation. So there isn't really a 'correct way to say it'.

"He hit his head on the wall" is a perfectly natural and grammatically correct sentence. It effectively communicates the action of striking one's head against a wall. The choice between "hit" and "bang" depends on the emphasis you want to place on the force or sound of the impact, but both sentences are grammatically correct and understandable.

No, I updated my question. Please rewrite your answer. I mean if "hit" means "touch something with force on purpose", can we say "he hit his head on the wall on purpose"?

I don't find on particularly natural in the cited context, because we nearly always use against in such contexts...

It's not a serious error, obviously. I wouldn't really notice it normally - but the OP here has specifically asked whether it's "natural". Which it isn't to me.
It's also worth noting that in the closely related context of rapping one's knuckles on / against a door, on is actually twice as common as against. But that's not exactly the same context. Another similar context is the car slammed against / into the wall, where you won't find any instances of on. In short, against works in far more contexts than on in this area, and is almost never "noticeably unusual", so that should be your default choice.

I'm not totally sure that this is right. I think "banging your head against a brick wall" might be a set idiom that's throwing off the results of the ngram. I get quite different results for "head on/against a door", and a reversed result for "hit my head on/against the" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hit+my+head+on+the%2Chit+my+head+against+the&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Admittedly, brick wall makes that specific usage more likely. I did that deliberately to amplify the difference. But as a general principle, against is a better preposition than on in contexts involving [forceful] impact, and imho that's what learners should be learning here.

He crashed against the ground (or) He crashed on the ground? Ngram results

@Mari-LouA: In that context it's neither. He crashed to / into the ground. The point is the general-purpose preposition on isn't usually the best choice for "impact" contexts - but obviously I'm not gonna argue with hit the nail on the head, regardless of whether it's literal or metaphoric.

"He crashed to the ground" suggests that a great height was involved whereas I was thinking of something closer to earth. But out of all the prepositions, without context, "crashed to" does work best.

No, I updated my question. Please rewrite your answer. I mean if "hit" means "touch something with force on purpose", can we say "he hit his head on the wall on purpose"?

Edit

he hit his head on the wall on purpose

The book The Triple Process Remedy has such a hit:

He hit his head on the wall and hated that he was totally useless.

The context is close to the OP's example, which is hence a valid usage.
Original Answer Before The OP's Revision
Yes, hit his head on the wall is
natural and has lots of matches in Google Books.
The phrase hit his head is also more common than bang his head.
Ngram.

No, I updated my question. Please rewrite your answer. I mean if "hit" means "touch something with force on purpose", can we say "he hit his head on the wall on purpose"?
